# Getting error messages while run a python code for execute a command in remotely linux server (ksh: spawn: not found)

Tags: python, linux, unix

I hope everyone is good , i just work with one python code for check status for spawn status , but always shown me this error message , while When i went to the server and write the same command it is working without any error.
path of the spawn in my server is :

```
Server01:> which spawn
/st/ex/sap/spawn/bin/spawncmd
```

ksh: spawn: not found

```
    import paramiko
    
    
    hostname = "yyy.com"
    user = "me"
    password = 'hello'
    commands = [  # "df -h",
        
        # "pwd"
        "spawn status"
    
    ]
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=user, password=password)
    except:
        print("can not do it ")
        exit()
    for command in commands:
        print("command", command, "commands")
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
        print(stdout.read().decode())
        err = stderr.read().decode()
        if err:
            print(err)
```

Any creative idea to solve this

Comment: How do you run the script? The interpreter specification `#!/bin/ksh` is wrong for a Python script. What happens when you manually log in to the remote system via `ssh` and try to execute "spawn status"? Please [edit] your question to add this information, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: The post has been updated

Comment: Log in manually and show the output of `which spawn` and `echo $PATH`. Then do the same from your script. I suspect that `which spawn` will show an error message when called from the script and that the value of `PATH` will be different.

Comment: Hi Bodo,

/st/ex/sap/spawn/bin/spawncmd --->

this is when i wrote which spawn

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information instead of answering in comments. Please re-read my previous comment and show **all** requested information.

Comment: Post has been Updated

Comment: I still don't see the output of `echo $PATH` both when you log in manually and when you run this from your script. I guess the directory `/st/ex/sap/spawn/bin` is missing when you run it from your script (or in any shell that is not a login shell). Which script adds this to `PATH`? (e.g. `.profile`, `.kshrc`, `/etc/profile`) Is there a typo in the output of `which spawn`: `/st/ex/sap/spawn/bin/spawncmd` with "spawn**cmd**"? Where does the "cmd" come from?